# how to convert a string value to integer without using Integer.parseInt()?

Tags: java

I have this input like

```
String s = "6" , ss="99 , sss = "99999";
```

i need to store these values in an int reference variable ,
without using Integer.parseInt

any suggestion ? , no full code , just the hints ??

Comment: One hint: `'6' - '0' = 6`

Comment: Take the code in `Integer.parseInt` and copy it to a new method.

Comment: "*without using `Integer.parseInt`*" why? This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `6 = 6*10^0`; `99 = 9*10^0 + 9*10^1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What about Scanner?

```
int a=new Scanner(s).nextInt();
```

Without util.

```
public static int parseInt(String s)
  {

    int ans=0;
      for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
          ans+=(s.charAt(i)-'0');
          ans*=10;
      }
      return ans/10;
  }
```

Comment: Other option `int i = new BigInteger("123").intValue();`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyStringToNumber {

    public static int convert_String_To_Number(String numStr){
         
        char ch[] = numStr.toCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        //get ascii value for zero
        int zeroAscii = (int)'0';
        for(char c:ch){
            int tmpAscii = (int)c;
            sum = (sum*10)+(tmpAscii-zeroAscii);
        }
        return sum;
    }
     
    public static void main(String a[]){
         
        System.out.println("\"3256\" == "+convert_String_To_Number("3256"));
        System.out.println("\"76289\" == "+convert_String_To_Number("76289"));
        System.out.println("\"90087\" == "+convert_String_To_Number("90087"));
    }
}
```

See more at [this URL](https://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/string-to-number/#sthash.9OnVBYnU.dpuf).

Comment: Add the second solution to the answer, it's hard to read as an unformatted comment - you can [edit] the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get each char from the string and then the value of each char. 0 has a value of 48 so

```
 char c = '9';
 int i = c - 48;
```

Now `i = 9`. After that you only need to multiply this value with the appropriate power of 10 and add it to the total

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConvertIntoInt {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        String numStr = "3256";
        char ch[] = numStr.toCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        // Get ASCII value for zero
        int zeroAscii = (int)'0';
        for (char c:ch) {
            int tmpAscii = (int)c;
            System.out.println("Temp Ascii:" + tmpAscii);
            sum = (sum * 10) + (tmpAscii - zeroAscii);
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```